# Where are reference to DirectX assemblies in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, reference, directx

I installed the new Visual Studio 2010. I want to create a C# Winform DirectX application, but I can't find the following assembly when adding the .Net reference list:

- Microsoft.DirectX
- Microsoft.DirectX.Direct3D
- Microsoft.DirectX.Direct3DX

How can I use DirectX with Visual Studio 2010?

Comment: Download the SDK separately, then you can link to them.

Comment: That is what I did but I still don't have nothing about DirectX...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DirectX is obsolete now, there are no DirectX assemblies. Use [XNA](http://creators.xna.com/en-US/) instead.

Comment: I perform some test but 
- XNA 3.1 isn't compatible with visual studio 2010...
- XNA 4 doesn't allow to build winform application including a XNA